# Верно ли, что слово "путь" в старину имело значение "должность"?

Tags: значение-слов, история

Верно ли, что слово "путь" в старину имело значение "должность"? Я слышал об этом от одного филолога, но нигде не нашел подтверждения.

Comment: см. также Ключевского . Сочинения в 9 томах. Том 6, стр. 150 (пути), также мой комментарий ниже (цитата из диссертации Ключевского)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот что нашлось в словаре [Даля](https://slovar.cc/rus/dal/572634.html):
**путь**
| самое место, учреждение, заведывавшее этим сбором; ведомство путного боярина или приказчика, управление дворцовыми имениями. Стольничий путь, ведомство стольника, собиравшего на дворе съестные припасы с сел; **стольник с путем, заведывавший дворцовыми волостями, для сбора припасов**. Сокольничий, ловчий путь, ведомство охоты; **вообще, боярин с путем, путный, при должности и с жалованием.**

Из [Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%B5):
[...начиная со второй половины XIV века...] Возникли так называемые ***путные бояре***, которые занимали **отдельные хозяйственные должности** при княжеском дворе, отдававшиеся им в кормление (например, конюший, сокольничий, чашничий, постельничий, окольничий, оружничий и др.).

Думаю, что это и имелось в виду: с путем — с должностью. Возможно, именно отсюда и пошло выражение *путный человек* — человек с положением, с должностью, при доходах.

Comment: Добавлю ещё [ссылку](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A6%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80) (см. в конце стр. и далее по ссылкам).

Comment: Думаю, что "путь" — это не "должность", а скорее "чин".

Comment: Не буду настаивать, но Даль пишет _при должности_, а не при чине. Ссылка хорошая, правильная.

Comment: В ссылке Царский двор есть 3-й источник. Это диссертация Ключевского на тему Боярской Думы. В ней Ключевский пишет прямо: "... пути были дворцовые ведомства, между которыми была разделена эксплуатация принадлежавших княжескому дворцу хозяйственных угодий." Чин -это боярин. Путь - это то, чем он распоряжается, с чего кормится и т.д.

Comment: + Ключевский. Сочинения в 9 томах. Том 6, стр. 150 (пути). По его мнению, *путный* в смысле толковый, полезный от смысла "польза", одно из развившихся значений слова ПУТЬ. (безнадежный человек, беспутный, в нем пути не будет и т.п.)

Answer (score 4):

Вот ещё статья, которая свидетельствует о том, что путь понимался не так однозначно. 
https://studexpo.ru/24245/istoriya/boyare_zemlevladeltsy 
В 14-16 веках высший класс служилых именуется "боярами введенными", т.е. введёнными во дворец для постоянной помощи великому князю в делах управления; они же получают кормления, т.е. наместничество в городах. Другой, низший разряд таких же дворцовых слуг называется путными боярами или путниками, получившими "путь"- **доход в заведование.**

Значение этих терминов не указывается в актах с достаточной ясностью и толкуется сбивчиво. Одна из причин этого в том, что на древнерусском деловом языке смысл слова **путь** колебался. Договорные грамоты князей обыкновенно упоминаются о боярах введенных и путных в связи с  привилегией освобождения от ратной службы во время осады города.

В некоторых старинных бумагах встречаем замечание об ином служилом человеке XIV - XV в., что он был у своего князя "боярин введенный и горододержавец", держал такие города без отнимки. *Зная, что значили пути на язык дворцовой хозяйственной администрации удельного времени, можно прежде всего подумать, что введенные или большие бояре были городовые наместники князя, пользовавшиеся доходами со своих административных округов, как кормлением, **а путные управляли путями, известными ведомствами центрального и дворцового хозяйства, получали содержание из доходов этих ведомств** и считались меньшими боярами сравнительно со введенными.* Но такое толкование возбуждает ряд затруднений. Притом **пути в значении кормления, т. е. дворцовые земли в пользование за службу давались не только меньшим слугам князя, но и большим боярам, не только управителям известных путных ведомств, но и дворцовым сановникам, ведомства которых не назывались путями: в актах XVI в. встречаем постельничих, крайчих, даже ключников "с путем".**

Вот почему и княжеские договорные грамоты XV в. не различают строго званий бояр введенных и путных: здесь свободными от повинности городной осады являются то бояре введенные и путные, то одни путные, но никогда одни введенные. Отсюда следует, что эти звания не были ни совместимы друг с другом, ни вполне тождественны. Они не исключали одно другого, но и не совпадали одно с другим, а только соприкасались: **введенные обыкновенно пользовались известными дворцовыми землями или доходами "в путь", на правах кормления, и потому считались путными боярами; но не все путники, пользовавшиеся такими кормлениями, были бояре введенные.**

Бояре введенные - управители отдельных ведомств дворцовой администрации или дворцового хозяйства, дворецкий, казначей, сокольничий, стольник, чашник и проч.
**Путными назывались все дворцовые чиновники, высшие и низшие, получавшие за службу дворцовые земли и доходы в путь или в кормление**.

Получается, что путь - это доход (кормление), т.е. и должность, и звание одновременно